# Improper integral

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{e^{x}}{1+x}dx$

Anyone know how to solve this? I have tried to find a substitute, or a function to compare with, but I don't have any clue whatsoever what to do. Wondered if someone could give me a hint.

Comment: This integral is divergent at the lower limit.

Comment: I need to be able to prove it

Comment: Note the for $x\in[-1,1]$, $\frac{e^x}{1+x}\ge \frac{e^{-1}}{1+x}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

As $\forall x: e^x\geq x$, we have:

$$\int_{a}^b\frac {e^x}{1+x}dx \geq \int_{a}^b \frac {x}{1+x}dx =\left(x-\ln(x+1)\right)\big|^{x=b}_{x=a} $$

Comment: Even more straightforward, $e^x\ge 1/e$ for $x\in [-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\int_{a}^1\frac{e^x}{x+1}\,dx\ge e^{-1}\int_{a}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x}\,dx
$$
for $-1<a<1$.